# FIXED - Can't download new Drummers on Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro, logic, download

Someone knows how to download the new drummers? I've clicked on the arrow pointing down (that's an international symbol for that!) and anything happens...

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: A possible solution would be it: https://logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=117724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED:**

```
 1. Create new channel
 2. Assign the Drum Machine Designer
 3. Open the library and resize until 3 columns show up
 4. Click on the down arrows that shows will that exists some missing downloads
```

*PS.: Doesn't matter where you look, no place else you can see that are missing it.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also manage this by going into the menubar and choosing:

```
Logic Pro X ▶ Sound Library ▶ Open Sound Library Manager …
```

… and selecting the drum kits that weren’t installed.

Comment: As I said, you are not able to see it there...